# Writing xml with qooxdoo

Tags: xml, api, qooxdoo

I've seen the api qx.xml.*
There is only three class. With these classes we can read.
What would be the recommended way to edit an xml file using the qooxdoo api?

Answer (score 3):

qooxdoo's qx.xml.* name space is basically a collection of static methods to abstract away some of the browser differences in working with XML documents. You start with one of the qx.xml.Document methods to create a document. What you get back is a native **browser document (DOM) object**. You then just use the API of this object, e.g. calling `.createElement()` to create a DOM element asf. If you then wanted to set an XML name space on the element, you could use qx.xml.Element.createSubElementNS() to do that in a cross-browser fashion. Similar considerations apply to serialization and XPath searches.

So the short answer to your question is: You use the qx.xml.Document class to parse the XML file into a DOM object. Then you use the DOM object's native API to manipulate ("edit") the document tree. For actions that vary across browsers, you resort to qx.xml.* static methods.

You can also look at the unit test class qx.test.Xml, to see more examples on using the API.

Comment: So the "cross browser" qx.xml.Document.create will create a native xml document, it's kind of wird!
I was looking for something more qooxdoo style (more cross browser)

Comment: And by the way it would be cool to have a xmlstore like the jsonstore